# Amazon Connect get Text-To-Speech messsage value from Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-connect

I am new to Amazon Connect and Lambda.

Regarding the "Text to Speech" feature of Prompts on Amazon Connect contact flows, under the "Enter Dynamically" option and then "Interpret As" - "Text".

Is it possible to pass message prompt value from a Lambda function to Amazon Connect contact flow prompt?
What I want to do is to dynamically change the message prompt value from the Lambda function.

For example on the contact flow prompt below, I want to dynamically pass and change the "Text" value from a Lambda function.

[image]

Comment: have a look here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/SynthesizeSpeechSamplePython.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return a string field from a database such as DynamoDB and then pass this to the contact flow. If your string starts with arn: then you are referring to prompt that has been stored or otherwise, you can play the text to speech via Polly.